# How to improve a regex for print range?

Tags: regex, vba

I would like to improve a VBA regex for a print range.

Currently I have this:

```
(\d+(-\d+)*)+(,\d+(-\d+)*)*
```

But, for an entry `12-25,45,50-53` this is returning the `,` and `-` like this:

Match 1: `-25`
Match 2: `,50-53`
Match 3: `-53`
and is not returning the `45`

Ideally I'd like a group returned for each comma delimited entry without any `,` or `-` like this:

Match 1: `(12-25)`
Match 2: `(45)`
Match 3: `(50-53)`

Comment: Let's "talk code": why not `Split(cellTextStrng, ",")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason 45 is not in a group is that you are repeating the second capturing group. When you are repeating a capturing group, the group contains the value of the last iteration.

So `(,\d+(-\d+)*)` will capture `,45`. Now the whole group is repeated due to the outer `*` and within that last iteration `,50` is captured by `,\d+` and `-53` is captured by `-\d+`

What you might do is match 1+ digits and use a single optional group for the hyphen and 1+ digits part to get 3 matches.

Use a positive lookahead `(?=,|$)` to assert what is directly on the right is a comma or the end of the string.

```
\d+(?:-\d+)?(?=,|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/10ULPn/1)

If you want 3 groups, you could use:

```
(\d+(?:-\d+)?),(\d+(?:-\d+)?),(\d+(?:-\d+)?)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/10ULPn/2)

Comment: I think I quite like the first option here as it's easier to modify to ensure there are no zeros entered which I'd forgotten about!!